# Why shouldn't the qdialog be used in forms?

Tags: quasar-framework

I want to use the q-dialog for a form with about 20 inputs. But in the documentation it is told that it should only be used for small quick things.

> From a UI perspective, you can think of Dialogs as a type of floating
> modal, which covers only a portion of the screen. This means Dialogs
> should only be used for quick user actions, like verifying a password,
> getting a short App notification or selecting an option or options
> quickly.

What should I use instead of Dialog for my modal forms ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quasar is a cross-platform framework. Its UI components are meant to be used for desktop and **mobile** devices. If you put a lot of child UI elements inside a Dialog on mobile devices, it won't fit in screen size and the whole idea of a dialog would fail. Thus, it's better if you make a dedicated view for your form with 20 inputs.

Comment: Actually that makes sense. You are saying that using it that way (with lots of input), it would overflow the view on mobile and would be more a ux design issue then a technical issue. And that is the only reason for `This means Dialogs should only be used for quick user actions`. So it won't be a problem as long as I design for desktop only. Is that correct?

Comment: As I am concerned, there are no technical issues.
It's just more pleasing in general for a user to have explicitly separate workspace for a long-term interaction with UI.
But if it's better for you and your users, then you don't have to be die-hard about recommendations.
By the way, there are a bunch of examples on Dialog's doc page, especially named "With containerized QLayout" one. Quite usable even on phone.